# Java compare method to sort array for Circular Look disk algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, comparator

I'm trying to make a custom comparator that will sort an array of integers in the order that a C-LOOK disk algorithm would perform.

I've implemented the Disk Queue as a PriorityQueue and the customer Comparator will be assigned to the Disk Queue list.

I am keeping track of the head position, and utilizing it in the compare method, but it's not quite right.

The first 5 operations added to the queue are [32, 188, 36, 61, 97].
The head position starts at 50.
But the first 5 operations after being sorted come out to be [32, 36, 188, 97, 61].

What else should I be doing?

```
private Comparator<Integer> CLOOK() {

    return new Comparator<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {

            if (o1 < o2) {

                if (o1 > currentHeadPosition) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return -1;
            }
            else if (o1 > o2) {

                if (o2 > currentHeadPosition) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 1;
            }
            else {

                return 0;
            }
        }

    };
}
// End CLOOK Comparator
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoah, did some more testing with the eclipse debugger and I found the solution myself.

```
private Comparator<Integer> CLOOK() {

    return new Comparator<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {

            if (Math.abs(currentHeadPosition - o1) < Math.abs(currentHeadPosition -  o2)) {

                if (o1 < currentHeadPosition) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return -1;
            } 
            else if (Math.abs(currentHeadPosition - o1) > Math.abs(currentHeadPosition - o2)) {

                if (o2 < currentHeadPosition) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 1;
            } 
            else {

                return 0;
            }
        }

    };
}
// End CLOOK Comparator
```